Why my socket value is always null when received from the Context Api
This is my main.jsx file(index.js)
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App.jsx";
import "./index.css";
import { RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import router from "./routes/index.jsx";
import { SocketProvider } from "./context/SocketContext.jsx";
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
<RouterProvider router={router}>
    <SocketProvider>
        <App />
    </SocketProvider>
</RouterProvider>
);

This is my App.jsx File
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext } from "react";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { Toaster } from "react-hot-toast";

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Toaster></Toaster>
            <Outlet></Outlet>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;

This is my SocketContext File
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const SocketContext = createContext(null);

export const SocketProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const socketInstance = io("http://localhost:4000");
        console.log("socket connected", socketInstance);
        setSocket(socketInstance);

        return () => {
            socketInstance.disconnect();
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <SocketContext.Provider value={socket}>
            {children}
        </SocketContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default SocketContext;

This is my Homepage.jsx file where I am consuming the context
import "./Homepage.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { Outlet, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";
import getRandomUsername from "../../helpers/getRandomUsername";
import SocketContext from "../../context/SocketContext.jsx";
const Homepage = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
    const [room, setRoom] = useState("");
    console.log(SocketContext);
    const socket = useContext(SocketContext);
    console.log("SocketConnection", socket);

    return (
        <div className="homepage">
            {Further data}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Homepage;

Even the console.log() in SocketContext is not printing anything and I think no request is even being made on the server as my server is not also printing anything on connection of client as it is supposed to do.
How can i solve this problem what could be the possible reasons for it

You Forgot to Connect Your Socket after Configuring it. you can do it like this. thats the Reason it is null
socket.on('connect', () => {
        console.log('Connected to the server');
        setSocket(socket);
    });

This way your server will connect and instance will be saved to your State variable.

This is a good call out but not actually an answer to the question which is about why the value from the context provider is null. Once you gain sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on posts
